# Adobe Reader after closing should remember page

Tags: windows, pdf, adobe-reader, ebook

I have here an Adobe Reader X - If im reading an ebook and closing and restart it the reader doesnt remember the page - it always start on page 1. I would like to continue after a restart there where I stopped. How to do that with the Adobe Reader?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply go to `Edit` > `Preferences` (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>).

Under Categories, choose `Documents`.

From here, click on `Restore last view settings when reopening documents`.

[image]

Comment: For me, this works for some files, but doesn't work for others. What could be the reason?